# How to notify the views when the database changes? (MVC, C#)

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, events, design-patterns

I'm thinking on a good design which is based on MVC and works with databases, but I have no idea how to notify the views of certain database-changes.. What technique to use, do I need more layers or not? How would you implement these?

Insert:
[image: Insert]

Update:
[image: Update]

Is it even possible, or should I stick to a refresh button on the views?

To make this more complicated, what if I have a view, about which I know it lists people, but I don't know if it displays the people's interests from another table? The view would just use the "Interests" property of the Person class, which then lazyloads the interests. Then if the name of an interest changes, the Central model notifies the views which list surely interests, but how to find out if there is a view which displays interests too?

Tohu va bohu is what is in my head now.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'notifying the views'.  Do you mean at runtime (ala ajax), or while coding (intellisense refactoring)?

Comment: Where's the controller in this? Wouldn't the controller talk to the Data Model, do the insert/update, and then reload the View?

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's going to be a desktop app, and yes, at runtime.
The controller.. well... my graph is missing that, but - as I think - it would do the same (reload the model) I asked: to notify certain views. Or maybe it's not the MVC which is the best for it. I just would like a basic conception to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Checking latest status of db from view by javascript is more applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In a Client - Server model (Asp.Net, web services etc), the client need to request the server for any information. Server wouldn't notify the client in any way.

May be you can implement an Ajax request periodically polling for the server/database changes.

Try something like a client script running every minute, to repeat requesting for the server changes.